# Displaying the escaped version of a string in python

Tags: python, string, printing

I have a string that has characters in it that when displayed in a terminal show up as spaces, tabs, etc. For example this string:

```
python -c 'print "".join([chr(ord(c)^ord(k) for c,k in zip("#
                                                                      8
$│6%#>└227,|o6d'f,n'x9+/7O&;&!<M9,>11␍ :
-               $&!|mhPzRdsOezthMqUssH|o*9O,:qI&z##
 %kHydlqA'd'%fm9O.
hoCx=gHs","JaHeJCaUTE")'Pa^j,{00:S`d91+%IaIxjZ%i6?8% &'k)$      bCz6,$N;
```

What I want to do is run through the string and create a "safe printable string" that will display the spaces, tabs, etc as escaped. For example from `string.printable`:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.printable
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
>>>
```

a tab should show up as `\t` a new line should show up as `\n`, etc.

How can I do this while being compatible with both python 2.x and python 3?

Comment: You want to escape *spaces*, too? What should those be escaped as?

Comment: @user2357112 spaces are fine, there shouldnt really be any spaces in the strings anyways

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just want `repr` ...

```
print(repr(my_string))
```

ie

```
s = """hello
world \xcc\x23\xee
"""
print(repr(s))
#'hello\nworld \xcc#\xee\n'
```